# Building Theme From Scratch – Header Not Showing

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m creating a website from scratch and my custom headers isn’t showing up.

Here’s my ***css*** code:

```
/*
* Blog name and description
*/
   #mainheader {
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
    } 
    .blog-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    }
```

Here’s my ***header*** code:

```
<body>
  <header id="mainheader">
   <div class="blog-header">
    <div id="blog-img">
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>
<div class="container">
```

and here’s my ***function.php*** code:

```
// Support Featured Images
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
//Add Custom header Settings
$args = array(
    'width'         => 1920,
    'height'        => 1080,
    'default-image' => get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/headers/lofsw.png',
    'uploads'       => true,
);
add_theme_support( 'custom-header', $args );
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function `get_header()` in your page template and ensure your header code is in a file named `header.php`.  Here's an example of an index.php file.

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container-wrap">
  
 <div class="container main-content">
  
  <div class="row">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: What should my header code be? Since I already have <?php get_header(); ?> on my index.php

Comment: HTML header code goes into header.php file in your theme directory.

Comment: I actually found a way to make it show up by adding ***theme.php*** and `get_header_image` . My problem now is that the header is taking up the whole website. How do I have it as a "fixed" size?

Comment: That's not using the convention of a WordPress theme.  Best to stick with the standard way.